# How to install azure-cli specific version(To test experimental feature)

Tags: linux, azure, azure-cli, azure-cli2

Currently, my az CLI version is 2.27.2
I would like to experiment with some extensions, to do this I require upgrading my version to 2.3.1(for Linux).

I already searched in the Microsoft docs but I seem unable to find the information that I need. Therefore I feel I require some help on upgrading the Azure CLI:

- List of available versions - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/azure-cli-extensions-list
- Insight on how to configure other versions - https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli#developer-setup

Comment: Stack Overflow! [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) and [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: The latest version of the Azure CLI is 2.27.2. Even if you try to upgrade azure cli version to latest using az upgrade command, you will get below  warning : 
You already have the latest azure-cli version: 2.27.2
I wonder where you found about  azure-cli version : 2.3.1 
Please provide reference

Comment: @RamaraoAdapa-MT in this link you can see the list of the different available CLI versions, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/azure-cli-extensions-list
And on this page on GitHub ( https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli#developer-setup ), we have the developer versions, which I, unfortunately, was unable to configure. I will also update the Question in this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As az cli version 2.3.1 is not released yet, you should be abled to use the extensions with your current version ( 2.27.2) as well.

For example, I am able to use account extension version 0.2.1 for which Required Minimum CLI Version 2.3.1 with my az cli 2.27.2 version

[image]